# Android 5.1+ / bring call screen on top during a call

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, bringtofront, android-dialer

Under certain conditions, I need to bring the dialer on top during an ongoing call. I used to use activityManager.getRunningTasks to look for "com.android.phone", and then use the activityManager.moveTaskToFront to bring the in-call screen to the front.
Unfortunately, with Lollipop, getRunningTasks is deprecated and only returns activity from my own app, so that no longer works.

So I tried using packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.dialer") and while starting that activity works, it doesn't get me to the call in progress but another screen.

Does anybody have another idea?
Please note that it needs to be the in-call screen (where you can mute, drop the call, etc.), not opening a new dialer to make a new call.